# Custom priority with the_content filter based on user input

Tags: plugins, filters

Currently, in my plugin Contextual Related Posts, I have an option to automatically add the related posts to the content using

```
add_filter('the_content,'ald_crp')
```

I know I can change the priority of the filter by adding a number greater than 10 (which is WordPress default).

```
add_filter('the_content,'ald_crp',20)
```

However, what I would like to do is let the user set the priority of the filter from within the options page which I can use and set the_content filter accordingly.

The plugin already has its own settings page.

My plugins doesn't use classes. It uses functions.

Any suggestions / code samples for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the priority in your options and pass that value to your `add_filter`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_81687_prepare_filter' );

function wpse_81687_prepare_filter()
{
    $my_options = get_option( 'my_options' );

    $priority = isset ( $my_options['content_filter_priority'] ) 
        ? $my_options['content_filter_priority'] 
        : 10;

    add_filter( 'the_content', 'ald_crp', $priority );
}
```

In my example I register the `the_content` filter during `template_redirect` because it is not needed earlier. You don’t need the filter in `wp-admin` or a login page.
You could even use `the_post` as hook instead of `template_redirect`. But then … another piece of code might call `echo apply_filters('the_content', $some_text );` without calling `setup_postdata()` before.

Comment: Would my_options be global if I don't enclose the code above within a function and directly put it into the .php file?

I've got a tonne of settings stored within my_options and I wouldn't like to make that a global variable since it would add unnecessary overhead on pages the related posts don't display

Comment: You can hide all this in a function or class method. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds good. I'll implement the same. Could you please highlight a bit on the `template_redirect` action.  The Codex page is very bare